Change Active Directory trust relationship attributes
I want to set some attributes of a trustedDomain object (All commands are typed into an elevated shell).
For an inbound trust, when I try this :
Set-ADObject -Identity "CN=corp.adds,CN=System,DC=tests,DC=adds" `
             -Replace @{'msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes'=([int]0x18)}

I've got this error :
+ Set-ADObject -Identity "CN=corp.adds,CN=System,DC=tests,DC= ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (CN=corp.ad...ts,DC=adds:ADObject) [Set-ADObject], ADIllegalModifyOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8311,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADObject

if I try this :
$trust = [ADSI]("LDAP://CN=corp.adds,CN=System,DC=tests,DC=adds")
$trust.'msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes' = ([int]0x18)
#OR THIS too : $trust.Put('msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes', ([int]0x18))
$trust.SetInfo()

I've got this error :
The server is unwilling to process the request

I have the same problem for outbound trust with 'trustAttributes' attribute
Despite the value is an integer actually, I am wondering if there is not some type problem. Or may be there is a way with .Net, I did not find it (trusts are created with [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().CreateTrustRelationship(...))
Any thoughts ? Thanks :)

It's been a while since I did this, but I remember having to use ksetup /setenctype rather than updating the attribute directly.

Oh, thanks, I have totally forgotten this command :) This will do the job job for now, but I will still looking for a more 'PowerShell way' to achieve this. It seems this cannot be straight a would need a DllImport to use some function (I am looking for it :)) not implemented in .Net

YW! You might be able to use a PE analyzer to enumerate functions imported by ksetup - I wouldn't be surprised if it uses a netlogon-related stub :)

Thanks again, I will try later, but  a quick look seems that  wldap32.dll is a good candidate :)

I was also attempting to change the trust object attributes but ran into the same issue.
Curiously there is a Get-ADTrust Powershell cmdlet but no Set-ADTrust.
The advice provided to me was to perform a reset of the trust:
NETDOM TRUST parent.domain /Domain:child.parent.domain /UserD:child\administrator /PasswordD:* /UserO:parent\administrator /PasswordO:* /Reset /TwoWay

This will set it back to the default values but may not accomplish setting the attributes to your preferred values.

Thanks, but this is not what I want to achieve ;)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
